# C++ polymorphic pointer cannot invoke member function

Tags: c++, pointers, polymorphism

I'm trying to set up a simple case to solve a textbook exercise. The code is on [IDEone](http://ideone.com/tzgSTI), and repeated below.

The code is a simplified case of trying to store a number of lists of animals, and being able to return any generic animal from one of these animal-specific lists held inside my wrapper queue.

I can add animals just fine and when trying to retrieve a dog, I appear to get a pointer to the dog since I can print its `name`. However, if I try to call its member function `speak()`, the code crashes and I can't figure out why.

```
class Animal {
public:
    virtual void speak() = 0;
    string name;
};

class Dog: public Animal {
public:
    Dog(string n) { this->name=n; }
    void speak() { cout<<name<<" says WOOF!"<<endl; }
};

class AnimalQueue {
    list<Dog> dogs;
    list<Cat> cats; // etc.
public:
    void enqueue(Animal* a) {
        Dog * d = dynamic_cast<Dog*>(a);
        if (d!=nullptr) dogs.push_back(*d);
        else // check for other animals, etc.
    }
    Dog* dequeueDog() {
        Dog * d = &(dogs.front());
        dogs.pop_front();
        return d;
    }
    Animal dequeueAny() {
        // Should return a random animal from any list
    }
};

int main() {
    // Set up
    AnimalQueue q;
    Dog * d;
    d = new Dog("Rex");
    q.enqueue(d);

    // Retrieve Rex
    d = q.dequeueDog();
    cout<<d->name<<endl;  // Prints "Rex"
    d->speak();           // Crashes?!

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Sorry, in cutting down my code, I eliminated the essence of the problem, which is that I should be able to add any sub-class of `Animal` to my list, and there's a special function called `dequeueAny()` which should be able to return a random `Animal` from any list. The code has been edited to include this (as well as my previously omitted `nullptr` checks when `enqueue`ing.

What's the best way to handle this? Is it to pass in a reference to an existing `Animal` object? Would that work? ie could, I have:

```
void dequeueAny(Animal * a) {
    // for example, let's return a Dog
    Dog d = dogs.front();
    dogs.pop_front();
    *a = d;
}
```

Admittedly, things like `dequeueDog()` should probably return a `Dog` by value.

Comment: Why doesn't Animal have a constructor that takes its name which dog calls? If `enqueue` can only reasonably handle dogs, why don't you make its parameter `Dog *`? Your code also leaks memory.

Comment: @NeilKirk: in which case, it should be renamed it to `enqueueDog()`, to match `dequeueDog()`.

Comment: If an `Animal` that is not a `Dog` is passed to `enqueue()`, `dynamic_cast` will return a NULL pointer, which you are storing in the list, but you are not checking for that anywhere. And `dequeueDog()` is also not checking if the list is empty before popping.

Comment: Consider `std::list<std::shared_ptr<Dog/Animal>>`

Comment: Your dequeue returns an invalid pointer.  The front element ceases to exist after you pop it.

Comment: Neil is right. `main()` is leaking `d`, because `enqueue()` **copies** the animal leaving the original alone, and `main()` is not calling `delete d`.  This code definitely should use `std::list<std::shared_ptr<Animal>>` (or `std::list<std::unique_ptr<Animal>>`) instead, and stop making copies of everything.

Comment: Or at the very least `list<Dog*>` or `list<Animal*>`, if you don't want to learn about smart pointers at this point. (But in that case make a note to learn about them later; they are helpful)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're returning the address of an element stored ([list::front](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/front/) returns a reference and you're taking the address of it) and then popping it ([list::pop_front](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/pop_front/) **destroys** the object):

```
Dog* dequeueDog() {
    Dog * d = &(dogs.front()); // Take the address of the front object
    dogs.pop_front(); // Destroy the front object
    return d; // Return the address to the deleted object (unsafe state)
}
```

Accessing memory through that pointer is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

A possible solution could be returning your object by value

```
class Animal {
public:
    virtual void speak() = 0;
    virtual ~Animal() {}; // Always a good thing if the class has virtual members
    string name;
};

class Dog : public Animal {
   ...  // unchanged
};

class AnimalQueue {
    list<Dog> dogs;
public:
    void enqueue(Animal* a) {
        Dog * d = dynamic_cast<Dog*>(a);
        dogs.push_back(*d); // This creates a copy of d and stores it
    }
    Dog dequeueDog() {
        Dog d = dogs.front(); // This creates a copy of the front element
        dogs.pop_front(); // Destroy the front element
        return d;
    }
};

int main() {

    AnimalQueue q;
    Dog * d;
    d = new Dog("Rex");
    q.enqueue(d);

    *d = q.dequeueDog();
    cout << d->name << endl;// Prints "Rex"
    d->speak(); // Prints WOFF

    delete d; // Free your memory

    return 0;
}
```

<kbd>[Example](http://ideone.com/mWRuEV)</kbd>

Please notice that you also forgot to free your memory thus causing a memory leak. Either use a [smart pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one) or free your memory and be a good citizen.

---

Edit: OP edited his question to specify he also needs a `dequeueAny` method. I strongly recommend not to edit your question after it has been answered (requirements should be as static as possible). Anyway in that case I would suggest you to use pointers (or smart pointers) instead of copying objects around

```
class AnimalQueue {
    std::list<Animal*> animals;
public:
    void enqueue(Animal* a) {
        animals.push_back(a); // Copy the pointer
    }
    Animal* dequeue() {
        Animal *d = animals.front();
        animals.pop_front(); // Destroy the pointer
        return d;
    }
};

int main() {
    AnimalQueue q;
    std::unique_ptr<Dog> d = std::make_unique<Dog>("Rex");
    q.enqueue(d.get()); // This will now store the pointer to the object

    // Try with dog-specific command
    Animal *sameDog = q.dequeue(); // d.get() and sameDog are now pointing at the same object
    if (d.get() == sameDog)
        std::cout << "d.get() == sameDog" << std::endl;
    std::cout << sameDog->name << std::endl;// Prints "Rex"
    sameDog->speak();

    return 0;
}
```

<kbd>[Example](http://ideone.com/UcUlNY)</kbd>

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear with my original question. So `Dog dequeueDog()` will work, and that's great, but I also want to be able to `dequeueAny()`, returning any random `Animal` (see edited question). Memory leak noted.

Comment: @Alec edited the question. Anyway I suggest you not to edit the requirements again (it invalidates the answers here given) and instead ask another different question

Answer (score 2):

```
Dog* dequeueDog() {
    Dog * d = &(dogs.front());
    dogs.pop_front();
    return d;
}
```

There you are taking a pointer to the front item in the list, **deleting** that item (by calling `pop_front`) and then returning a dangling pointer.